# (Java/Android) Add size filter to files list from Array

Tags: arraylist, filtering

I have script for Android listing all images from sdcard memory. Code below:

**SkanerActivity.java**

```
package com.click;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.google.common.base.Predicates;
import com.google.common.collect.Collections2;
import com.google.common.collect.Lists;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;



public class SkanerActivity extends Activity {
    private File root;
    private ArrayList<File> fileList = new ArrayList<File>();
    private LinearLayout view;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_skaner);



        view = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.view);

        //getting SDcard root path
        root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                .getAbsolutePath());
        getfile(root);

        for (int i = 0; i < fileList.size(); i++) {
            TextView textView = new TextView(this);
            textView.setText(fileList.get(i).getName());
            textView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);

            System.out.println(fileList.get(i).getName());

            if (fileList.get(i).isDirectory()) {
                textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF0000"));
            }
            view.addView(textView);
        }

    }

    public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
        File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
        if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

                if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                    getfile(listFile[i]);

                } else {
                    if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".png")
                            || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                            || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                            || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".gif"))

                    {
                        fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                    }
                }

            }
        }
        return fileList;

    }
}
```

And **activity_skaner.xml**

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="8dp" >
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I would like to filter list of files with one more parameter - size of file - to exclude from results files below 500 kb. How it could be possible with this code?

Many thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `dir.listFiles();` returns an array of `File` objects (`File[]`).

`listFile[i]` is a `File` object.

`listFile[i].length()` returns the size of file in bytes.

```
500kb = 500 * 1024.
```

So, I would modify your `getfile` method like this:

```
public ArrayList<File> getfile(File dir) {
    File listFile[] = dir.listFiles();
    if (listFile != null && listFile.length > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < listFile.length; i++) {

            if (listFile[i].isDirectory()) {
                fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                getfile(listFile[i]);

            } else if (listFile[i].length() >= 500 * 1024) {
                if (listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".png")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpg")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".jpeg")
                        || listFile[i].getName().endsWith(".gif"))

                {
                    fileList.add(listFile[i]);
                }
            }

        }
    }
    return fileList;

}
```